# How to retrieve each item in a ListBox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I am new to C#, although I did take a quarter of Java last year. I have an assignment due tomorrow, so here is my question. I made a sample little program just so I can hopefully get what I'm looking for. I am wondering, how the heck do I look at the listBox and say, for example, if the item soccer is selected, do one thing, but if anything else is selected, do another thing? I will upload a piece of code that doesn't do what its supposed to do, and you all can call me stupid, and then give me the answer.

```
    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string best;
        best = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if ((string)namesListBox.SelectedItem == "Soccer") 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fried chicken, don't let that bird die in vain.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Long long ago, in the land of the Hobbit...");
        }
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Every time this code runs, I always get Long, long ago.... That is not what I want to see. Any help would be appreciated, I'm about to give up on this program. This is not the actual program, that one is alot more complicated, I just made this one to demonstrate my question... Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you simple try to MessageBox the SelectedItem property? What do you see then?

Comment: A good first step would be to call `MessageBox.Show(namesListBox.SelectedItem);`, or--even better--just put a breakpoint in your code and see what the value is. It will be very illuminating.

Comment: C# does not have List Boxes. Windows Forms and WPF both have List Boxes (similar but different!). Please tag the appropriate UI Framework as well as C#.

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint in the click method. This allows you to inspect the variables at runtime. See: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: @crashmstr He is clearly new--maybe just point out that there is a distinction between the language and the UI Framework. (Edited--I initially interpreted your comment as snark, but I think I jumped the gun--apologies)

Comment: In addition to debugging your app, as Olivier has mentioned above, consider posting the items you are populating your list box with.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with case-sensitivity.

Comment: @FarhanAnam That's what I suspect!

Comment: Until the poster adds something of the things asked with these comments  to his question there is no way to exactly tell what's the reason of the 'error' here. Voting to close because the poster fails to add  code that reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuriy,

It looks like you are casing the selected item to a string. I have a feeling this may be the problem.

What exactly are you using the string 'best' for? you defined it, but it is not used in your example.

Is this what you are looking for? Try using the ToString() method, and trim it so that whitespace will not throw your code off:

```
string selectedItem = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();

if (selectedItem == "Soccer")
    MessageBox.Show("Soccer is selected.");
else
    MessageBox.Show("NOT SELECTED");
```

Maybe it is a casing error? If you don't want to worry about uppercase or lowercase, try appending .ToLower() to your string:

```
string selectedItem = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim().ToLower();

if (selectedItem == "Soccer".ToLower())
    // Handle code accordingly.
else
    // Handle accordingly.
```

You can also search your ListBox for a string and find out where it is. Then determine whether the user has selected that particular item:

```
int selIndex = namesListBox.FindString("Soccer");
```

This will return a zero-based index of the location of the first item containing the word "Soccer" in it.

Now handle the selected index:

```
if (namesListBox.SelectedIndex != -1 &&
    namesListBox.SelectedIndex == selIndex)
    MessageBox.Show("First item containing \"Soccer\" is selected.");
else
    MessageBox.Show("First item containing \"Soccer\" is not selected.");
```

It is also quite possible that you are using a ListView object rather than an actual ListBox. If this is the case, you will have to take a different approach. This example still uses your *ListBox* name:

```
// This assumes that you cannot select multiple items, and that you
// only have one column in your ListView.
string selectedItem = namesListBox.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;

if (selectedItem.Trim() == "Soccer") // Continue as before...
```

Does this work with your project?

EDIT:
Wait. Are you trying to change the selected item to "best" before evaluating?

If so, do it like this:

```
int selIndex = namesListBox.SelectedIndex;

namesListBox.Items.RemoveAt(selIndex);
namesListBox.Items.Insert(selIndex, "best");
```

EDIT:

Be sure to include code that handles no selection:

```
// Will not execute block of code if nothing is selected.
if (namesListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No item is selected.");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using WPF, and you are using ListBox like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstGames">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Soccor"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Cricket"/>
    </ListBox>
```

Replace this `best = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();` with

```
best = ((ListBoxItem)namesListBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

and accordingly others too.

Because if you are using itemssource property of ListBox and binding say list of only strings, then your present code will work for you surely, if you have checked UpperCase/LowerCase.

If you are using some item like a Game object with multiple properties then your code won't work and more can be said if you tell how you are binding your listbox to a collection object.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was looking for was how to write an if statement and this part of the code you wrote worked perfectly. I guess I had whitespace throwing it off, or I was just overthinking it. But anyhow, my issue is resolved. Thank you very much.

```
string selectedItem = namesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();

if (selectedItem == "Soccer")
    MessageBox.Show("Soccer is selected.");
else
    MessageBox.Show("NOT SELECTED");
```